# Javascript test regex for falsy value

Tags: javascript, regex, knockout.js

**Note: This is not a question about testing for a valid email format but rather how to test for `false` the right way. I'm trying to avoid (another) regex debate :-)**

I am using knockout to show or hide an error based on whether the input value is a valid email. Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" id='email' data-bind="textInput:email" />
<p data-bind="visible: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(email()) == false"> Email must be valid.</p>

var signup = {        
    email:ko.observable("")
};
ko.applyBindings(signup);
```

My question is whether testing if the regex is `== false` is browser safe or do different browsers treat this differently. I am testing in chrome and it seems to work fine. If this is not the correct way to do it, is there a way to test for the inverse of true with the regex itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `!!regex`, to convert it to a `bool`. However, in an `if` statement, this is done anyway (depending of what you are checking against - it would do for `true` and `false`).

So to answer your question: Yes, your method is browser-safe / cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Is it "correct"? That depends on what you mean by "correct". Yes, it'll work, but have a look at e.g. [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test), emphasis mine:

> The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. **Returns `true` or `false`.**

So no need to compare it to a boolean, nor any need for the `!!` idiom - though neither would hurt functionality-wise.

One thing to note though, warranting this additional answer IMO, is that you should probably not place that logic inside your *view*, but utilize a `computed` instead to place it inside your view model instead:

```html
<input type="text" id="email" data-bind="textInput: email" />
<p data-bind="visible: email.isValid">Email must be valid.</p>
```

```js
var signup = {        
    email: ko.observable("")
};

signup.email.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
    return /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i.test(signup.email());
});

ko.applyBindings(signup);
```

This code will work fine cross-browser, most likely including IE versions down to levels I'd rather not think about. If you insist on adding some code-wise hint that `isValid` returns a boolean (apart from its name and the unit tests you should perhaps write), I'd prefer the `!!` idiom mentioned in the other answer over comparing with `false` as you do in the question.